# Social media sharing

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, query-string, sharing

I would like to create a set of buttons that will share to various social media websites (Twitter, Facebook, Tumblr etc).

I am currently working on the Twitter sharer, I've been looking around and can't find any custom code that will take the current URL and append this to the web address without forcing me to use the Twitter share icon rather than my own custom icon.

Here's the site I am working on (links down the right hand side): http://www2.hull.ac.uk/files/tfa/index/content2.html

Here's my current code:

```
<a href="javascript:popup_share('http://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20this%20page#tfa&url=')" class="twitter-share-button">
                                    Twitter
                                    <b></b>
                                </a>

<script>
    var pageName = window.location.toString();
    alert('http://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20this%20page#tfa&url=' + pageName);
</script>
```

I can't work out how to add the string in the alert box to the already present a tag!

The URL needs to be created dynamically though as I want it to be site wide and will not know the URLs every time - This is the URL to be shared to whichever platform. I have already looked on the Twitter website but can't find anything that will do this without me having to know the website address.

Can anyone offer any help for this?

Many thanks!

Comment: give http://www.addthis.com/ a try. It's easier to implement and you can set all share types you want, plus have analytics on the sharing part.

Answer (score 3):

The link should just be

```
<a href="#" class="twitter-share-button">Twitter</a>
```

The JavaScript should add the click event

```
$( function(){
    $(".twitter-share-button").click( function(e){
        popup_share('http://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20this%20page#tfa&url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong because it's not coming up with anything on any browser :\    `code`<script>$( function(){
    $(".twitter-share-button").click( function(e){
        popup_share('http://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20this%20page#tfa&url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});</script>
<a href="#" class="twitter-share-button">Twitter</a>`code`

Comment: I'd throw an alert at the start of the click handler function and at the start of the first function just to make sure they're executed. Are you getting any script errors in your browser?

Comment: No script errors and the alert box appears just not getting a pop up. Does it work for you?